# Google Maps Polyline to Postgis with Java/Hibernate

Tags: java, maps, polygon, google-polyline

I have a page where the user enters the starting point and ending point and I show de route in the map. I would like to know how to get this polygon (polyline) and save it in Postgis through the Java / Hibernate.

Someone can help me?

Thanks.
Luciano

Answer (score 0):

Usually you cannot get that polyline as vector data coordinates, because these data are provided either by `Teleatlas / Tomtom` (via `Google` service) or `Microsoft Bing` (Navteq data) or `Nokia` (`Navteq` data)

Such vector data are extremly expensive, and therfore you can only request that a line is drawn on the screen, but you will not get the geographical coordinates (latitude, longitude).
 Even `Google` would not have the right to give you that vector data (because they dont own that data, they only display it).

However, I remeber a post here showing how to use an unofficial `Google` server where you can request the route between two geo points, and get back a compressed encoded route.
But you legally cannot use that service, nor I do know if it yet exists.

An alternative would be use open source map data, like `OpenStreetMap`, for these services you can get the vector data for a route. For example: the ios `RouteMe` library provides such  things via `OpenStreetMap`.